# jQuery can't get celIndex

Tags: jquery, html

I can't get the cellIndex of a cell in a row. Code looks like this:

jQuery JS:

```
if (jQuery('td'[value='someValue'])) {
  var cellIndex = jQuery(this).cellIndex;
  console.log(cellIndex);
}
```

And the html:

```
<tr>
   <td>someValue</td>
</tr>
```

I hope you get, what i mean, thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cellIndex` is a property of the underlying DOM Element, not a jQuery object. Therefore you can either use `prop()`:

```
var cellIndex = $(this).prop('cellIndex');
```

Or you can use the `this` keyword as a direct reference to the element itself:

```
var cellIndex = this.cellIndex;
```

You should also note that your opening selector has some syntax errors. It should presumably be:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  if ($('td[value="someValue"]')) {
    // ... 
  }
});
```

Although even this has an issue as `value` is not a standard attribute of a `td`. If you want to store custom data in an element use a `data-*` attribute instead.

Comment: I have got an opening selector, that is a Directive in AngularJS (I know, its old) that loads after an element was rendered in the DOM. I just need to know, how to get the cellIndex of a cell with a specific value, to go into another table and go to the same cellIndex, to be in the same column. Also the ".prop('cellIndex')" doesn't work for me ... the console says it is "undefined".